# Auto import annotations in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to auto import annotations in IntelliJ?
When I place the cursor on @Entity annotation and press ALT+Enter. I don't find a option to add:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

Does any configuration need to be done to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your editor preferences (open using shortcuts  ⌘, (macOS), or Ctrl+Alt+S (Windows/Linux)).

Go to Editor > General > Auto Import, be sure the correct values are checked. It should look similar to this:
[image]